# Change DateTime() offset in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Is it possible in PHP to change the `DateTime()` to a custom time difference. Like adding it 20 min and everytime I call `new DateTime()` I would get those extra 20 min to the current date.

I thought about [**__construct()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) but didn't see how to fix it.

I can use a function of course, but just curious to know if its possible to change the prototype `new DateTime()`

Comment: You can `extend` the class to implement your own behaviour

Comment: create a user-defined function?

Comment: @Bojangles, how can I extend the class? can you point me out some reading?

Comment: @dayuloli, yes, I mentioned that. Thanks

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Comment: @Bojangles: the better would be to create another class that would produce modified `DateTime`s

Comment: @zerkms What's wrong with extending the `DateTime` class?

Comment: @Bojangles: because you're not extending it. You just need a way to produce `DateTime` objects with 20 minutes shift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify("+20 minutes"); //or whatever value you want
```

[Example online](http://ideone.com/tQoKLa)

Answer (score 1):

Ilia Rostovtsev's answer is a good one for achieving your goal. Alternatively you can also use the DateInterval class with DateTime::add(). Personally, I prefer that one because you don't need to know how strings need to look like while DateInterval uses a standard like P1d for a day.

I wouldn't use inheritance to get a DateTime class including your wished behaviour. Instead you can create some kind of factory which contains Ilia's code (and every other code that is part for the object creation). The interval can be added as parameter. Your added interval, your 20 minutes should be stored in a constant in case you need to change that interval in the future while technically being able to use other intervals than 20 minutes.

Comment: could you add a example for that?

Comment: I created 3 examples on the following page:

[link](http://3v4l.org/JnGR2) 

I'm not a big fan of static methods because they are hard or even not able to be mocked in unittests but it's up to you how you class and method looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in one line:-

```
$date = (new \DateTime())->add(new \DateInterval('PT20M'));
```

That would be my preferred way of doing it.

[See it working in PHP >= 5.3](http://3v4l.org/3dUE6)